# Specify position of curved label in QGIS?

Tags: labeling, qgis-2.14

From this answer in 2012 underdark stated:

> BUT you won't be able to have curved labels anymore if you move/rotate the labels manually, as far as I know.

It's now 2016, and I noticed that I can enable the `Curved` radio button *and* specify coordinates for my label (see below). However when I specify these coordinates, my label is no longer curved.

[image]

**I want to specify a particular orientation for curved label around a circular buffer (which I've converted to a polyline), is there a way to do this?**